# Unable to build web applications with VS 2019

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2019

I installed VS 2019 Pro and tried to compile our solution just to get this:

```
error MSB4226: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
 Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" was not found. Also, tried
 to find "WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" in the fallback search path(s) for $(VSToolsPath) - "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Mi
crosoft\VisualStudio\v15.0" . These search paths are defined in "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\
Bin\MSBuild.exe.Config". Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk in one of the search paths
```

Here is why it happens:

1. Our projects all include the following import statement: `<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.VisualStudioVersion.v*.Common.props" Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == ''" />`
2. `MSBuildExtensionsPath = C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild`
3. `MSBuildToolsVersion = Current`
4. The folder `$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)` indeed exists, see below.

`$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)`:

```
C:\> dir "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current"


    Directory: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----        6/13/2019   9:11 PM                Bin
d-----        5/27/2019   4:42 PM                Imports
d-----        5/27/2019   4:41 PM                Microsoft.Common.targets
d-----        5/27/2019   4:42 PM                SolutionFile
-a----        5/27/2019   4:38 PM          13606 Microsoft.Common.props
-a----        5/27/2019   4:38 PM            789 Microsoft.VisualStudioVersion.v15.Common.props
-a----        5/27/2019   4:38 PM           2029 THIRDPARTYNOTICES.txt


C:\>
```

So, VS 2019 actually loads `Microsoft.VisualStudioVersion.v15.Common.props`. And what is inside? Observe:

```
C:\> cat "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Microsoft.VisualStudioVersion.v15.Common.props"
<!--
***********************************************************************************************
Microsoft.VisualStudio.v15.Common.props

WARNING:  DO NOT MODIFY this file unless you are knowledgeable about MSBuild and have
          created a backup copy.  Incorrect changes to this file will make it
          impossible to load or build your projects from the command-line or the IDE.

Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
***********************************************************************************************
-->

<Project>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <VisualStudioVersion>15.0</VisualStudioVersion>
    <VSToolsPath>$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)</VSToolsPath>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
C:\>
```

So, at the end `VSToolsPath` is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0` which is obviously wrong, because no such directory exists. What does exist is v16.0.

Anyway, it seems the root cause for all of this is `c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild` communicates to the world that MSBuild 15 is version to be used instead of MSBuild 16.

What am I missing?

Comment: You can choose to remove the statement `<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.VisualStudioVersion.v*.Common.props" Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == ''" />` or move it to the correct position but not the very top in xx.csproj file. Not sure why you need this statement cause in VS2017 and VS2019, create a new web app and check its project file, this statement is not necessary.

Comment: I need a little bit time to digest your answer.

Comment: During build process, the msbuild will read the xx.csproj in an order from the beginning to the end(line1 to end line). So if you put the extra statement above the definition of VSToolsPath property, which will affect the normal build logic, which causes this issue I think. I'm not sure about the reason why you add the statement, but in VS2017 and VS2019, I think it's not necessary in normal structure of project file. Then the easily way to resolve the issue is to remove the statement.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Our projects all include the following import statement: `<Import
>   Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.VisualStudioVersion.v*.Common.props"
>   Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == ''" />`

I guess the root cause of the issue is that you **put the statement above the definition of `VSToolsPath` property**.

Create a simple asp.net web application(.net framework) in VS2019 and its structure looks like this:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />

  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    ...
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    ...
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    ...
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    ...
  </ItemGroup>

  <!--Position 1-->
  <!--<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.VisualStudioVersion.v*.Common.props" Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == ''" />--> <!--Position 1-->
  <PropertyGroup>
    <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">10.0</VisualStudioVersion>
    <VSToolsPath Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)</VSToolsPath> <!--This is where the VSToolsPath is defined.-->
  </PropertyGroup>

  <!--Position 2-->
  <!--<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.VisualStudioVersion.v*.Common.props" Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == ''" />--> <!--Position 2-->
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
  <Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' != ''" /> <!--This is where the error finally occurs.-->
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="false" />
  <ProjectExtensions>
    ...
  </ProjectExtensions>
  <!-- To modify your build process, add your task inside one of the targets below and uncomment it. ...-->
</Project>
```

I assume you may add the statement in the top of the xx.csproj file or somewhere above the

```
<VSToolsPath Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)</VSToolsPath>
```

If so, since now $(VSToolsPath) is not defined yet. Its value is empty, then the build system will execute the Import element in your statement to Import `$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.VisualStudioVersion.v*.Common.props` file, which will then result in the `VisualStudioVersion` property be set 15.0 instead of 16.0.

And since it import properties from `Microsoft.VisualStudioVersion.v15.Common.props`, the  `VSToolsPath` is now set as `$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0`, and this will cause the final error you get since the part of the path to `Microsoft.WebApplication.targets` file is $(VSToolsPath). See:

```
<Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' != ''" /> <!--This is where the error finally occurs.-->
```

So if you add your statement above the first definition of $(VSToolsPath) like **position 1**, you'll get this error. If you add your statement below the definition of $(VSToolsPath) and above the `Import of Microsoft.WebApplication.targets` like **position 2**, all works well.

**Update1:**

About the info of Import element see [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/import-element-msbuild?view=vs-2019#remarks).  ***imported projects are inspected in the order that they are imported.***

**Update2:**

Hint from **mark**, I post an issue in msbuild. [The link](https://github.com/microsoft/msbuild/issues/4728).

Comment: I removed `<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.VisualStudioVersion.v*.Common.props" Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == ''" />` from our code and made sure each and every project imports Microsoft.Common.props. But I still think it is a bug that *c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current* contains directory 15 instead of 16 and it has a file *Microsoft.VisualStudioVersion.v15.Common.props*

Comment: @mark You're right, it should contain xxx.v16.xxx instead of xxx.v15.xxx, I've just checked the folder structure of different versions of VS, for VS2019, it should be v16.xxx. So it's why your statement may work well in VS2015, 2017 but not VS2019. I will post this issue to DC or github/msbuild and then share the link in update later:) Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 4):

For me, the following worked.

In the csproj file,

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" />
```

is replaced with

```
<Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" />
```

Comment: Worked for me. A straightforward fix.

Comment: Worked for VS2022