# C# Unit Tests run in Azure DevOps but not in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, azure, unit-testing

I need to add a Unit Test in an existing Visual Studio solution with 100s of tests. I wrote a simple Unit Test only to check if it is working.

**My test code is:**

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System;

namespace Training.UnitTests
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(1, 1); 
        }
    }
}
```

The projects used in the Visual Studio solution are of `**SDK-Style**`. Now when I try to run all the tests, I found that some of the tests run and some of test do not run as shown in the screenshot below (including my newly added sample test).

[image]

I do not understand why some tests are running and some tests do not run at all in Visual Studio's Test Explorer. ***All of these tests run fine in the Azure DevOps pipeline***. I even tried to run my sample test individually in Visual Studio by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> but the test only builds not run. But if

Following are the sample project files of the UnitTest projects which run and those wo do not run.

**.csproj of a running Project**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <Import Project="..\..\..\..\_Solution\build.defaults.targets" />
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net472</TargetFramework>
        <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
        <GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>true</GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>
        <IsCodedUITest>False</IsCodedUITest>
        <TestProjectType>UnitTest</TestProjectType>
        <OutputPath>$(SolutionDir)SystemTests\$(Configuration)</OutputPath>
        <AssemblyTitle>SystemTest</AssemblyTitle>
        <DebugType>full</DebugType>
        <LangVersion>8</LangVersion>
        <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
        <Optimize>false</Optimize>
        <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
        <AssemblyName>SystemTest.Bus</AssemblyName>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\TeamTest\Microsoft.TestTools.targets" Condition="Exists('$(VSToolsPath)\TeamTest\Microsoft.TestTools.targets')" />
    
    <ItemGroup>
        <Reference Include="PresentationCore" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestAdapter" Version="$(MSTestTestAdapterNugetVersion)" />
      <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestFramework" Version="$(MSTestTestAdapterNugetVersion)" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="$(MicrosoftNETTestSdkNugetVersion)" />
        <PackageReference Include="FluentAssertions" Version="$(FluentAssertionsNugetVersion)" />
    </ItemGroup>
    
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\..\UnitTestSetups.csproj" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\Bus.Impl.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Target Name="CopyCustomContent" AfterTargets="AfterBuild">
    <Copy SourceFiles="..\..\..\..\_Solution\automation.runsettings" DestinationFolder="$(OutDir)" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

**.csproj file of a NOT running project:**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">  
  <Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\TeamTest\Microsoft.TestTools.targets" Condition="Exists('$(VSToolsPath)\TeamTest\Microsoft.TestTools.targets')" />
  <Import Project="..\..\..\..\_Solution\build.defaults.targets" />

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net472</TargetFramework>
    <ProjectTypeGuids>{3AC096D0-A1C2-E12C-1390-A8335801FDAB};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
    <VSToolsPath Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)</VSToolsPath>
    <ReferencePath>$(ProgramFiles)\Common Files\microsoft shared\VSTT\$(VisualStudioVersion)\UITestExtensionPackages</ReferencePath>
    <IsCodedUITest>False</IsCodedUITest>
    <TestProjectType>UnitTest</TestProjectType>
    <OutputPath>$(SolutionDir)\Tests\$(Configuration)</OutputPath>
    <AssemblyTitle>Training.UnitTests</AssemblyTitle>
    <LangVersion>8</LangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  
    <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="PresentationFramework" />
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.ComponentModel.Composition" />
    <Reference Include="System.Configuration" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="WindowsBase" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="FluentAssertions" Version="$(FluentAssertionsNugetVersion)" />
    <PackageReference Include="Moq" Version="$(MoqNugetVersion)" />
    <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestAdapter" Version="$(MSTestTestAdapterNugetVersion)" />
    <PackageReference Include="MSTest.TestFramework" Version="$(MSTestTestAdapterNugetVersion)" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="$(MicrosoftNETTestSdkNugetVersion)" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Caliburn.Micro" Version="$(VcSimNugetVersion)" />
  </ItemGroup>
  
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\Training.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

**QUESTION:** Why only some of the UnitTests are running in **Visual Studio's Test Explorer**? The test which do not run in VS **run fine in Azure DevOps** pipeline.

Comment: Question: do you have all tests in the same project? The one that is not running in VS, is their other tests in the same project that are running?

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio: Either all the tests of a project runs or none of the test runs.

Comment: but is it random or a particular project never runs?

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio: It is not random. I always get the same result as shown in the screenshot. There is a set of projects (each consisting of multiple unit tests) that never runs, while some other projects (each consisting of multiple unit tests)  always run. That's why I have posted the `.csproj`  files of both the types of projects.

Comment: try removing  <VSToolsPath Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)'  from the csproj which is not running

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio: Thanks a lot! It worked. Please convert your comment to answer and also explain a bit why `VSToolsPath Condition` was not letting the tests to run in VS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparing both csprojs, I noticed the one which contains the tests that are not running contains the following line:

```
 <VSToolsPath Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)</VSToolsPath>
```

I've checked a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57865000/1384539) and I believed the above line was either in the wrong place or not being used, reason why I've first recommended removing it to validate my assumption. It turns out it was not being used and after removing, it solved your problem.